# Is Project server 2013 integraion with TFS supported when Project Server running on webapplication with claims authentication?

Tags: project-server

Is Project server 2013 integraion with TFS supported when Project Server running on webapplication with claims authentication?

I am getting same error as mentiond in below URL. Please help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0d3798f-04dd-45b9-b5af-354bf4242dc3/error-tf244069-an-error-occurred-while-checking-the-provisioning-status-of-the-report-ing-database

Thanks in advance...